# Index out of range when committing (Fluent NHibernate)

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net-mvc, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

**SOLVED**

Turns out it was my foreign keys messing with me. Once I removed them it worked like a charm. Weird...

I'm new to the magic world of Fluent NHibernate and I've run into some trouble. I have two tables in my database that are related. These are *messages* and *users*. The relation should be that **one** user can have **many** messages sent and **many** messages recieved.
For this, I've created two maps. One for messages and one for users. I use MySQL as database.
*Users*

```
    Id(x => x.Id);
    Map(x => x.Username).Not.Nullable();
    Map(x => x.Password).Not.Nullable();
    Map(x => x.Email).Not.Nullable();         
    Map(x => x.Firstname);
    Map(x => x.Surname);
    Map(x => x.Salt);
    Map(x => x.Privilege);
    HasMany(x => x.Messages).KeyColumn("msg_to_userid").ReadOnly();
    HasMany(x => x.SentMessages).KeyColumn("msg_from_userid").ReadOnly();
    Table("users");
```

*Messages*

```
    Id(x => x.Id, "msg_id");
    Map(x => x.Title, "msg_title");
    Map(x => x.ToId, "msg_to_userid").Not.Nullable();
    Map(x => x.FromId, "msg_from_userid").Not.Nullable();
    Map(x => x.DateTime, "msg_datetime");
    Map(x => x.Content, "msg_message");
    Map(x => x.Read, "msg_read");
    References(x => x.To, "msg_to_userid").ReadOnly();
    References(x => x.From, "msg_from_userid").ReadOnly();
    Table("messages");
```

The table structure for users

```
CREATE TABLE `users` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `username` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `password` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `salt` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(75) NOT NULL,
  `firstname` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `surname` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `privilege` tinyint(2) DEFAULT '1',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=6 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

And the structure for messages:

```
CREATE TABLE `messages` (
  `msg_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `msg_title` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `msg_from_userid` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `msg_to_userid` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `msg_datetime` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `msg_message` longtext,
  `msg_read` bit(1) DEFAULT b'0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`msg_id`),
  KEY `fk_messages_users_idx` (`msg_from_userid`),
  KEY `fk_msgtouserid_users_idx` (`msg_to_userid`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_msgfromuserid_users` FOREIGN KEY (`msg_from_userid`) REFERENCES `users` (`id`) ON DELETE SET NULL ON UPDATE SET NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=15 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

As you can see, I have two foregin keys in messages. One to get the user that sent and one to get the user that recieved.

When I have data I just use begin transaction and commit(). What I find odd is that I can select and fetch data without any troubles. For example I can see all my messages but when I try to update or save a new one it fails.

The error message I recieve is of type **IndexOutOfRangeException** with the message of: Parameter index is out of range.
Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SOLVED

Turns out it was my foreign keys messing with me. Once I removed them it worked. I assume it is best to add foregin keys after the mapping is done in NHibernate. Then it's easier to know what went wrong and what keys do not work.